# I would like to know why word count package is missing from the Hadoop package?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

```
~ ❯❯❯ cd hadoop-3.2.1
~/hadoop-3.2.1 ❯❯❯ ls
LICENSE.txt README.txt  etc         lib         sbin
NOTICE.txt  bin         include     libexec     share
```

Comment: Consider using the text formatting options available here.

Answer (score 0):

The executable examples are located in a JAR under the share folder

`bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar`

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation